# Disable zooming in header and footer only in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to have in my JQuery Mobile application both header and footer on a fixed position and, when the user pinches or zooms the front end, only the content area will become bigger or smaller while the header and footer will remainthe same size. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be cool in some cases, but mobile browsers don't like fixing things on the screen and don't really support it. JQM makes some tricks, but not with zooming.

If you want you could disable scaling in meta viewport (set max and min), but that might not be the best thing to do in some apps.